# Is is possible to set communities user email notification settings with apex?

Tags: email, community, notification

Im working on a communities implementation for a customer and they are hoping to have a way for users to set their email setting options as part of a custom signup process.

Is it possible to access a users various email settings, including group email notifications in apex for use in a visualforce page?

Answer (score 1):

If your looking to control group email notifications then it is possible, but you would do this with the GroupMember Object.  You can access the groupmember object where the userId matches the userID you are looking for and set the Group attribute of 'Send Group Emails' to true.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm

**A snippet from the Object Model**

[image]

**And the link to the documentation**

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_users.htm

Comment: Hmm interesting.... im not seeing the Send Group Emails attribute?  is that on GroupMember?  I dont see it in workbench either? https://www.dropbox.com/s/dq20j9rjap6pakh/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-29%20at%205.32.51%20PM.png

Comment: No it is on the Group object, but you can access it from the the GroupMember Object

Comment: But I'm trying to change the users notification setting, not settings for the whole group?

Answer (score 0):

Community email/chatter preferences for a user are on the NetworkMember object.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_networkmember.htm